# OpenApi. Specify generic response

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm using OpenApi v3 for documenting with Swagger but I have a parametrized type in response that extends from a class like CustomResponse. In OpenApi for documenting response @Schema(implementation=MyClass.class) but I cannot do this with the generic like CustomResponse.class.

Someone knows how I can do this with OpenApi v3?

Thanks for your responses.

Empty